# How to reverse all arrays inside an object

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = {
 id: 1,
 track: {
  "1": [
   {x: 10, y: 10},
            {x: 11, y: 11},
            {x: 12, y: 12}
  ],
  "2": [
   {x: 10, y: 10},
            {x: 11, y: 11},
            {x: 12, y: 12}
  ]
 }
}

console.log(data.track);
var rev = data.track["1"].reverse();
console.log(rev);
```

How can i reverse every array inside "track" object? But I showed you above, that i am able to reverse array, by selecting it by key, but can i literally reverse every array inside "track" object?

Comment: yes, you literally can

Comment: Have you tried going over `data` using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.keys() to find all keys in your data structure

```
    var data = {
     id: 1,
     track: {
      "1": [
       {x: 10, y: 10},
          {x: 11, y: 11},
          {x: 12, y: 12}
      ],
      "2": [
       {x: 10, y: 10},
          {x: 11, y: 11},
          {x: 12, y: 12}
      ]
     }
    }


    var keys = Object.keys(data.track);
    var count = keys.length;
    
    for (var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      var rev = data.track[keys[i]].reverse();
      console.log(rev);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just loop the `data.track` to get reverse result.

```
for (var i in data.track) {
    console.log(data.track[i].reverse());
}
```